# if then logic inside expect script

Tags: bash, expect

I have an expect script I use for ssh. Some of my hosts prompt with the RSA host key text and some do not. How can I setup my script for an if/then in expect. Here is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set ipaddress [lindex $argv 0];
spawn ssh user@$ipaddress
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"
send "yes\r"
expect "user@$ipaddress's password:"
send "password\r"
set prompt {\$ $}
expect -re $prompt
send "$command\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "quit\r"
interact
```

The part I need to build in the if/then logic are these two lines:

```
expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"
send "yes\r"
```

The logic flow would be:

```
if expect "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"
then send "yes\r"
else
expect "user@$ipaddress's password:"
etc..
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is working for me with the following code modifications.

```
expect {
    "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" {
         send "yes\r"
         exp_continue
    }
    "user@$ipaddress's password:" {
         send "password\r"
    }
    }
```

Comment: You've got the `exp_continue` in the wrong place: it should be in the "are you sure" block. Because in both cases you have to hit the password.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your suggestion. I have not had a single failure yet since moving exp_continue so it seems you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to "blindly" accept the host key you could do something like what's suggested here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/123072/ssh-automatically-accept-keys

There are a couple of suggestions - the ssh-keyscan method being the more secure way.